# Using strtotime and taking timezone into consideration

Tags: php, timezone

I have a system running in PHP and am using CodeIgniter (if there is a CI specific answer to this I would be happy as well).

I often need to figure out the timestamp of dates such as "this Thursday" or "this Monday". I currently use `strtotime("this Thursday")` and it gives me what I ask for.

I have a server in EST. It is 01:00 (1:00am), early morning Friday, Feb 24, 2012 in New York.

I have a user who has specified his timezone to be Pacific time. Right now it is 22:00 (10pm) late evening Thursday Feb 23, 2012 in San Francisco.

I use `strtotime("this Thursday")`. Since my server is in EST, it returns me the timestamp for March 1, 2012. I would like to take the user's timezone into consideration. For my user, "this Thursday" should return Feb 23, 2012.

Can I use `strtotime("this Thursday")` for it, and if so, how would I specify the target timezone?

If not, what approach would you suggest to getting the date for "this Thursday" in a specific timezone.

Comment: Your server's date is in the future!

Comment: Absolutely! I was using a contrived example. Soon enough it will be in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out that strtotime takes a $now parameter. I can specify the $now param to be the current time in the user's timezone and strtotime returns me what I need.

Comment: While this works in some / most / 99%+ cases, due to daylight saving differences (not on same date) etc. it is better to change the timezone one is working in. There are some tiny inconsistencies when just altering the time but keeping the wrong timezone. Rare, and depending on use you might never run into them, but there nonetheless.

Comment: It looks like my time var contains a timezone in it. When I print out the "T" component it shows the correct user timezone.

Comment: Are you very sure? Because that sounds like you set the timezone _somewhere_ as the input of `$now` is just a humble, simple integer....

Answer (score 1):

The [`manual for strtotime`](http://www.php.net/strtotime) links directly to [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://www.php.net/strtotime). I would take that as a hint to use that.

Answer (score 0):

This is taken string from the php site

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Shanghai');

$first_day_of_month = date('Y-m',time()) . '-01 00:00:01';
$t = strtotime($first_day_of_month);
print_r(array(
            date('Y-m',$t),
            date('Y-m',strtotime('- 1 month',$t)),
            date('Y-m',strtotime('- 2 month',$t)),
));
?>
```